# list of node that there attribute

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I need a list of all the Attribute **ID**(the value) of Descendants(Frame) that have an Attribute **SecondFeature** (Descendants-ObjectClass) that equal **Vehicle**.
(there is node that have 1 "object", other 2/3 time and other not at all)
this is a part of the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <Frame ID="120">
<PTZData Zoom="1.000" />
- <Object ID="5">
 <ObjectClass SecondFeature="vehicle" /> 
</Object>
</Frame>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with following [XPath expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx):

```
var xml = // your XML string here
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var frameIds = doc.Root.XPathSelectElements(
        "//Frame[./Object/ObjectClass[@SecondFeature ='Vehicle']]")
    .Select(n => n.Attribute("ID").Value);
```

Naturally, if your `Frame` nodes can be present without `ID` attributes, you'll need extra null checks in `.Select`.

Alternatively, non-xpath appraoch (but this is IMHO less readable and calls for even more caution):

```
var frameIds = doc
    .Descendants("ObjectClass")
    .Where(n => n.Attribute("SecondFeature").Value == "Vehicle")
    .Select(n => n.Parent.Parent.Attribute("ID").Value);
```